# Enviar querystring em uma requisição com PHP

Tags: php, http

Preciso realizar acesso a uma página que tem uma query pré determinada, mas não quero que o usuário seja redirecionado para página, apenas envie a requisição.

Comment: Para enviar requisições pode usar o `curl` ou o `file_get_contents()` e pegar o resultado.

Comment: @rray  como seria um exemplo ? Tipo quero fazer requisição a google.com/q=1

Comment: Procure na documentação, tem exemplos bem claros. Desculpe se pareci arrogante, mas isso irá te ajudar no futuro.

Comment: é um webservice ou uma página comum?

Comment: Veja o [exemplo 4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) é um bom começo, se precisar de mais alguma coisa avisa aí.

Comment: obrigado irei testar, @rray escreve uma resposta por favor

Comment: Poxa porque me deixou no vácuo? É webservice ou página normal?

Comment: O que você quer é passar uma query na querystring http? Se for isso veja a resposta.

Comment: A ideia é um sistema de arduino, progamei para pegar comando na url (ex. Ip/virardireita) porem o arduino e pobre em layout, iria montar em outro server e apenas enviar comando.

Comment: não está claro se pretende fazer isso do lado server ou do lado cliente.. Se for a partir do lado cliente, uma requisição ajax resolve, se for pelo server, teria que usar recursos do php como curl, fopen, etc. Mas no comentário vc fala de arduino, o que já muda muito as direções.. ESpecifique melhor a pergunta.

Comment: A ideia e apenas requerer a pagina, pois é a que liga e desliga , montaria uma pagina em outro server q acesso e exec a função ...

Comment: @AugustoFurlan pelo seu exemplo `google.com/q=1` acho que a minha resposta resolve teu problema não?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  irei testar ...

Answer (score 0):

- **[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)**

  O `curl` requer em alguns servidores tenham habilitado, todavia pode tentar habilitar por php.ini, remova o `;` de `;extension=...`, por exemplo:

  ```
  ;Windows server
  extension=php_curl.dll

  ;Like-unix server
  extension=curl.so
  ```

  Exemplo:

  ```
  $query = urlencode('Olá mundo');

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com.br/?q=' . $query);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $resposta = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $resposta;
  ```
- **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**:

  ```
  <?php
  // Create a stream
  $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n"
     )
  );

  $context = stream_context_create($opts);

  $query = urlencode('Olá mundo');

  $resposta = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com.br/?q=' . $query, false, $context);

  echo $resposta;
  ```
- **[fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)**:

  Se for fazer download de um arquivo grande talvez `file_get_contents` e `curl` tenham problemas de despejo de memória, por isso segue um exemplo com `fsockopen` que ajuda a resolver isto:

  ```
  $query = urlencode('olá mundo');

  $fp = fsockopen("www.google.com.br", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
  if (!$fp) {
      echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
  } else {
      $out  = "GET /?q=' . $query . ' HTTP/1.1\r\n";
      $out .= "Host: www.google.com.br\r\n";
      $out .= "User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '\r\n";
      $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

      fwrite($fp, $out);

      while (false === feof($fp)) {
          echo fgets($fp, 128);
      }
      fclose($fp);
  }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Cara, por que você não usa javascript para fazer esse GET? Você pode usar isso aqui:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var url = "http://url.com";
       $.get(url, function(response){
           // Executar alguma coisa com a resposta do endereço
           console.log(response);
       });
  });
</script>
```